# How to use the Singleton pattern via inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, singleton

I am trying to use the Singleton design pattern via my abstract Charcter class so all sub classes can acces the object instance. Here is my singleton class:

```
 class GatewayAccess

{
private static GatewayAccess ph;

// Constructor is 'protected'
protected GatewayAccess()
{
}

public static GatewayAccess Instance()
{
  // Uses lazy initialization.
  // Note: this is not thread safe.
  if (ph == null)
  {
      ph = new GatewayAccess();
      Console.WriteLine("This is the instance");
  }

  return ph;
}
}
```

I can use this in my program.cs to create an instance no problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GameEngine multiplayer = new GameEngine(5);

        Character Thor = new Warrior();
        Thor.Name = "Raymond";
        Thor.Display();
        Thor.PerformFight();
        Thor.PerformFight();
        multiplayer.Attach(Thor);

        GatewayAccess s1 = GatewayAccess.Instance();
        GatewayAccess s2 = GatewayAccess.Instance();

        if (s1 == s2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("They are the same");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Thor.getGamestate());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

So what I want to do is allow the subclasses ie, warrior to access the instance of the Gateway, I just cannot figure out how to do this as the inheritance stuff is confusing me. Basically the gateway access is an access point to a database that can only have one connection at once. The singleton pattern was easy enough to understand, its just the mix of that and the inheritance. I was hoping once I achieved this, I could then do it in a thread safe manner.

I was also wondering how the Singleton instance could be dropped, as it is a connection to a database and can only be used by one character object at a time, then once the character object is done with it, it must free the singleton object up right?

I tried to use methods in my Character class to do all this but it isn't working.

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Just... don't. [Singletons are not cool](http://jalf.dk/singleton/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sense several design smells here.

- DB connection should not be Singleton - as you yourself mention, connections come and go, while the main point of Singleton is that it stays for the app's lifetime
- Singleton and thread safety are not a good match
- Game characters should not have to work with the gateway (c'mon, what is a warrior to do with a database? ;-)

You should better separate concerns and have DB / persistence handled by a different class which calls the game characters rather than vice versa.

It is difficult to give more specific advice with the little information you provided.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, design patterns are a pain, I have spent A LOT of time researching the singleton as well as other patterns. I will consider your suggestions, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `static class`, instead of singletone, you can not extend it and can not create an instance of it. Plus, you can use it in way you want, by simply invoking a `static` unctions on it, and it internally can keep track of the state of `private static connection` member.

**EDIT**

Just a *pseudocode* example:

```
public static class Connector
{
    static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...); //return type object, 
                                                       //just for example, choose more 
                                                       //appropriate type for you.

    public static object GetData(string query)
    {
       con.Open();

       //run query and retrieve results

       con.Close();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there, could you show me an example of how to do this, it sounds like it may be a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Singleton is definitely not good pattern, when it is supposed to be used by one object only. Why don't you create it as non-static field of that Character class and destroy it in IDispose.Dispose()? If you still want singleton, make 'ph' protected and then you can access it as GatewayAccess.ph

Comment: Through all the research I have done, I see more negative comments with regards to the Singleton pattern than anything else. I need to implement it in my coursework, that is the only reason I am continuing on with it, otherwise I wouldn't waste my time :(